# Transfer blog content from Umbraco 4 to Umbraco 7

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

We have an old site using umbraco 4, and we are trying to migrate the blog posts (which may be around a 1000) to a new site in Umbraco 7.

We've tried searching online, but results are mostly paid services who cannot migrate into umbraco as well.

Anyone have any ideas?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem exactly a year ago. I can't script this for you but the solution is this:

Go into the database and check the tables. Go in the current Umbraco 4 system and check which fields exist and which ones have content that you want. Then go to the Umbraco 7 system and create exact same doctypes, fields, tabs etc with the same names.

Do basically the same with the database. Then pull the data from the old one to the new one with a database script.

Wish you luck, took me quite a while.

There's no tool I know that will do this for you effectively.

Comment: thanks man. Yeah we were able to export the info from Umbraco 4 through packages. We got the XML file. But getting error messages when importing in umbraco 7. I'll try your approach. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't actually think about the XML file, but we did a database first approach. However, check Robert Foster's answer. There's this tool, it just didn't work for us.

Answer (score 0):

Soeteman Software's CMS Import tool is perfect for this - there is a free version capable of importing 500 records at a time that may suit your purposes:

https://soetemansoftware.nl/cmsimport

Comment: That's true, this tool exists, however, in our case it didn't actually work, as we had not only more than 500 but long story short it wasn't doing its job as it should. We were missing things and decided to script it on our own. He does mention they're about 1000 too.